# What is the difference between the following tfds.load() calls?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp, tokenize

I'm new to NLP and just started getting into tensorflow, I'm curious as to why

```
imdb_sentences =[]
train = tfds.as_numpy(tfds.load('imdb_reviews',split='train'))

for item in train:
    imdb_sentences.append(str(item['text']))

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=10000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(imdb_sentences)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(imdb_sentences)
```

returns no error and works fine but,

```
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test) = tfds.as_numpy(tfds.load('imdb_reviews',split=['train','test'],batch_size=-1,as_supervised=True))

x_train=list(x_train)

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=10000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_train)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train)
```

returns this:

> > **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'**

Why is there a type mismatch if imdb_sentences and x_train contain the exact same data and both are of type list?

Answer (score 0):

If you print the first element of `imdb_sentences`:

```
['b"This was an absolutely terrible movie. Don\'t be ..."']
```

This is the first element of `x_train` in the second scenario:

```
[b"This was an absolutely terrible movie. Don't be ..."]
```

See the difference?

Just transform the content of `x_train` to string, something like the code below, and it will work:

```
x_train=list(x_train)
x_train = [str(elem) for elem in x_train]
```

Comment: Has this solved your issue? If so make sure to accept it by toggling the check mark on the left side of the answer.